# Trouble Inserting Data into MySqlDatabase with parameters in ASP.net (vb.net)

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net, parameters

I'm having some problems when I try to insert data to my database(mysql). It seems my connection isn't working, but I doubt it because I can retrieve data from it yet no luck on inserting.
I've also tried various things and I still can't come up with a solution nor find the cause of error.

Can somebody help me out? Your concern is very much appreciated!

### Here's my Registration.aspx page

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.Web.Security
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Web.Configuration
Imports System.Configuration
Partial Class Register
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim ctc As New Class1
    Dim conn As MySqlConnection
    Dim connstr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbconn").ConnectionString
    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand
    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Try
            conn = New MySqlConnection(connstr)
            conn.Open()

            cmd = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_uinfo (user_id, fname, lname, email, pword, paypal) values (null,@fname,@lname,@email,@pword,@paypal)")
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@fname", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 45).Value = firstname.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@lname", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 45).Value = lastname.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 45).Value = email.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@pword", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 250).Value = password2.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@paypal", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 45).Value = paypal.Text

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()



            conn.Dispose()
            conn.Close()
            cmd.Dispose()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Registration failed." & ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

---

### Here's my ConnectionString (web.config)

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="dbconn" connectionString="server=localhost;database=db_aspweb;user id=root; pwd=root"/>
    </connectionStrings>
```

---

### My Database

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_uinfo` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pword` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `paypal` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
  UNIQUE KEY `paypal` (`paypal`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

---

### The error I am getting so far

"Registration Failed. Connection must be valid and open."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the connection (connstr) to the command object (cmd) either by constructor or property.

Comment: So that's what I'm missing. Thanks for reminding me! @Lolo



`cmd = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_uinfo (user_id, fname, lname, email, pword, paypal) values (null,@fname,@lname,@email,@pword,@paypal)", conn)`